# How to do I call a function in another running class?

Tags: java, swing, function, class, jframe

So I have one `JFrame`, and then when I click a button it opens another `JFrame` in another class with a simple `ActivityWindow.main(new String[] {""});`. Then, when I exit out of the created `JFrame`, I need to update the first `JFrame` because the data has changed. What I'm wondering, is how can I call a function for the first `JFrame` class, from the created `JFrame` class? Like, I know that I can do something like `MainWindow.read();` (where `read()` is a function), but that executes the function in this class, not that one.

Also making a timer for the first `JFrame` to update automatically is not an option.

Comment: please share mcve(minimal complete verifiable example) of your code

Comment: Submit a reference to the instance of the first `JFrame` to the second `JFrame` when you create it. You can then change the first one using the reference.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) @depperm Great advice, and a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment will auto-expand as seen in my first comment (complete with link).

Comment: In reference to point (2) above, note that this situation seems best coded using a `JOptionPane` or modal `JDialog` instead of the second frame. Query the values immediately after the call to set it visible, and they will be processed as soon as it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `public` method in the 1st JFrame.

   ```
   public void changesToFrame(){
        ....
   }
   ```
2. Create another instance variable to hold the parent JFrame and another constructor in the second `JFrame`.

   ```
   JFrame jf1; 

   public NewJFrame(JFrame jf1){
       this(); //calls the default constructor
       this.jf1 = jf1;
   }
   ```
3. Now pass the parent `JFrame` upon creating the second one.

   ```
   JFrame jf2 = new JFrame2(this);
   ```
4. Then you can simply call the `changesToFrame()` method of the first `JFrame` within the second.

   ```
   jf1.changesToFrame();
   ```

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've been in this situation where the second `JFrame` is a huge one with hours invested in designing and coding. In that case modal dialog is not the best option.

Comment: *"with hours invested in designing and coding"* Your 'fix' is an hack to cover a bad design. A design that should be changed before proceeding. Minus one for not only suggesting bad practices to the OP, but more for doing so without considering they might want to do it the right way.